# How to figure out which Prettier rule is breached in VSCode

Tags: node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

I have a .eslintrc file that also includes prettier rules. I use VS Code to code in React and Node.js. I have the following line:

```
const { variable1, variable2 , variable3 , variable4 } = req.body
```

Prettier forces me to put "req.body" on the next line. I have both ESLint and Prettier extensions installed on my VSCode. How can I figure out which rule should I change in my config so that prettier would let me keep this on the same line?

```
{
  "env": {
    "node": true,
    "es6": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended"
  ],
  "globals": {
    "Atomics": "readonly",
    "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
  },
  "plugins": [
    "prettier",
    "@typescript-eslint",
    "simple-import-sort",
    "import"
  ],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 11,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "rules": {
    "quotes": [
      "error",
      "single",
      {
        "avoidEscape": true
      }
    ],
    "prettier/prettier": [
      "error",
      {
        "singleQuote": true,
        "semi": false
      }
    ],
    "semi": [
      "error",
      "never"
    ],
    "no-trailing-spaces": "error",
    "block-spacing": "error",
    "no-var": "error",
    "keyword-spacing": "error",
    "no-multiple-empty-lines": [
      "error",
      {
        "max": 2,
        "maxEOF": 1
      }
    ],
    "eol-last": [
      "error",
      "always"
    ],
    "no-unused-vars": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "error",
    "simple-import-sort/exports": "error",
    "simple-import-sort/imports": [
      "error",
      {
        "groups": [
          // Packages
          [
            "^@?\\w"
          ],
          // Side effect imports.
          [
            "^\\u0000"
          ],
          // Internal packages.
          [
            "^(@|@pkg|utils|config|vendored-lib)(/.*|$)"
          ],
          // Parent imports. Put `..` last.
          [
            "^\\.\\.(?!/?$)",
            "^\\.\\./?$"
          ],
          // Other relative imports. Put same-folder imports and `.` last.
          [
            "^\\./(?=.*/)(?!/?$)",
            "^\\.(?!/?$)",
            "^\\./?$"
          ]
        ]
      }
    ],
    "import/first": "error",
    "import/newline-after-import": "error",
    "import/no-duplicates": "error"
  },
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": [
        "*.ts"
      ],
      "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
      "plugins": [
        "@typescript-eslint"
      ],
      "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just added an option "printWidth": 120 to "prettier" config.